# onClick a button setState to a value in reactjs instead of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing an onClick event on a button to set a `value: 0`, but at first click, it gives "undefined" value.

I have set the state of `value` to `null` in constructor

#### Handler function code

```
sitHandler = () => {
  this.setState({
        robotButtons: { value: 0, eventTime: Date.now() }
    });
 //am calling a socket here to send these new setState 'robotButtons' 
 data
    console.log(this.state.robotButtons);
}
```

and here is my button with click event

```
<Button className="robot-control-button" onClick={this.handleSit}>
```

I have tried using `e.preventdefault(e)` but it throws an error.

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: Please add your full code with jsx and siteHandler

Answer (score 1):

You need to write console in callback because setState takes some time to update value.

```
this.setState({
    robotButtons: { value: 0, eventTime: Date.now() }
},function(){
   console.log(this.state.robotButtons);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`e.preventDefault()` throws error because event is not passed.

Use like this.

```
<Button className="robot-control-button" onClick={(e)=>this.handleSit(e)}>
```

And the code is

`e.preventDefault();` not `e.preventdefault(e)`

make sure you are receiving event in `handleSit`  like handleSit(e) { .... }

Your handler function should be like this

```
sitHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  this.setState({
        robotButtons: { value: 0, eventTime: Date.now() }
    });
 //am calling a socket here to send these new setState 'robotButtons'  data
    console.log(this.state.robotButtons); // this will not work, as setState is a asynchronous call. You need to use callback function as second paramenter,
}
```

`console.log(this.state.robotButtons);` this will not work, as setState is a asynchronous call. You need to use callback function as second paramenter,

the code should be

```
 this.setState({
        robotButtons: { value: 0, eventTime: Date.now() }
    }, ()=> {
     console.log(this.state.robotButtons);
     // call socket connection here
});
```

Comment: after using callback function its working fine with the values, thanks for the help and information about asynchronous call of setState @kiranvj

Comment: @Niki State update may be asynchronous, React may batch multiple `setState()` calls into a single update for performance. More info here https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous